# creating a visible on load Pre-loader Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Trying to replicate the pre-loader [page](http://www.ryanedy.com) on load the SVG and a background image appears and as soon as the user scrolls the page scrolls to the content and the page-loader is not visible or can be reached again unless you refresh the page, not sure how to tackle this, any help to point me in the right direction would be great- I have tried diseminating the said page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what your code looks like and what you have been trying so far.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways to accomplish this, a simple starting point could be something like this:

basic html outline:

```
<div id="loader">
LOADING Image/content
</div>

<div id="body">
website body
</div>
```

CSS

```
#body{display:none;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#loader").hide();
$("#body").show();
});
```

noscript fallback

```
<noscript>
<style>#loader{display:none;}#body{display:block !important;}</style>
</noscript>
```

Basically, this code has two divs the loader and the body, the body is set as display none in the CSS. When the page is ready, jquery is triggered to hide the loader and show the body.

The noscript fall back will set body to visible when javascript is disabled.

There are multiple ways to accomplish, this is just one idea.

Answer (score 0):

Out of one of a hundred different ways, my initial thoughts were along these lines:

- Wrap your main content in a wrapper with position relative and give it an offset from the top by 100% of the window width
- Make the page-loader 100% height and width and position fixed
- Offset the wrapper before the page is fully loaded, and then just transition it to 0 offset once the page had loaded

[See a working `jsfiddle` here](https://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/ew1gn4pz/)

Comment: Thank you, I took a look at the fiddle, I was wanting the page loader to remain until the user initiates through a click event or scroll event, so just a stab in the dark here would I attach an event listener to the js too?????

Comment: @MichaelWhite Yeah exactly, replace the settimeout with an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an element (Div) that covers the whole screen.
2. Behind it (smaller z-index) add a Div container that holds all the images.
3. Add in JavaScript a load event function to all images:

   image.onload = function() {
   //image was loaded

   }
4. Hide the cover Div when all images was loaded.
5. How to know when all images were loaded? add a counter or use a Promise.
6. Add overflow: none to disable scrolling, and add click event or scroll event (using jQuery) and set overflow to auto.

There are a lot of ways to implement each of these sections.